# Order of parents' names for kohen on gravestone

Tags: kohen-priest, gravestone-inscription

I can't find examples of gravestones (matsevot) with both parents' names in Hebrew. For a kohen, the options seem to be

> Ploni ben Almoni ha-kohen v'Almonit

which I don't especially like, as it makes the mother sound like kind of an afterthought;

> Ploni, ben Almoni v'Almonit, ha-kohen

which I like, but the two commas are crucial, otherwise it seems to be saying that the mother is a kohen; or

> Ploni ben Almonit v'Almoni ha-kohen

which is syntactically correct but a bit odd, as we generally don't put the mother's name first.

Is there an accepted right way? Are there sources or examples (I can't imagine any earlier than the 20th century)? Are there other better options?

Thanks.

Comment: Why is Ploni ben Almoni ha-kohen v'Almonit an afterthought? Let's say Almoni had three names, like: Reuven ben Yechezkel Menachem Eliyahu v'Almoniti. Is that also an afterthought? So why does "Ha-Kohen" make it seem that way? Also, I don't see how the comma makes your second example any more correct.

Comment: Another possibility: _P'loni hakohen ben Almoni v'Almonis_

Comment: You realize that the traditional way doesn't mention the mother's name at all, hence what you're looking for is fairly rare.

Comment: I can show you an example of one with both parents, but as neither was a kohen, it won't answer your question. You might want to refine your first line to include that request.

Comment: @robev: I've edited to add another comma. What I mean is the difference between "John son of Richard and Jane the dentist", which is ambiguous, and "John, son of Richard and Jane, the dentist" where it is clear that John is the dentist.

Comment: @msh210 although that it makes it sound like Almoni may not have been a kohen

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. Traditionally the mother's name isn't mentioned. If you are going to mention it anyway then you aren't going to find a traditional proof for how to do so. What are you seeking here? How somebody 20 years ago made up how to do it? Is that better than how you make up how to do it? Is seeking that even on topic?

Comment: @JoelK it's impossible for Ploni to be a Kohen if his father isn't, so it wouldn't imply that.

Comment: @robev It’s impossible for Almonit to be a kohen, but the OP is still worried about possible ambiguities

Comment: @JoelK maybe she's a bas kohen

Comment: @robev she still wouldn’t be a kohen. Maybe a kohenet...

Comment: @robev, and Joel K -- You're right, there's no real ambiguity, of course his mother isn't a kohen. That's why, to my ear, the female name next to "ha-kohen" is jarring. Answering Double AA, since there isn't a standard for this, I'm looking for whatever precedent there is, plus information on what's clear and idiomatic as Hebrew is not my first language.